# Doing Tic Tac Toe game with GUI interface on java, facing runtime error after including new method

Tags: java, runtime, infinite-sequence

So I am making a tic tac toe game with user friendly GUI interface.  I have almost completed the game but there seems to be a problem with my checkWin function.  Up to this point, everything was working just fine until I added the checkWin function and the parameters associated it with it.  Before I implemented the checkWin function, you would press a button, it would be marked X and then there would be an automated computer move that would place an O randomly on the board where there isn't an X.  Code is posted below.  When I run the code, and you press a button, the applet just freezes and you can't even exit out of it without end task, ctrl-alt-del...  Again, everything worked fine up until the checkWin function and now I'm facing a run-time error.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TicGUI extends JFrame 
    {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");                    //Global frame and grid button variables 
  JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
  JButton start = new JButton("Start");              //Create start/reset buttons for game
  JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
  JOptionPane turn;
  int moveCounter = 9;
  boolean gameWon = false;


 public TicGUI()                                        //Tic tac default constructor which adds and dimensions Jframe
   {
     super();
     frame.setSize(350, 450);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        //Setting dimension of Jframe and setting parameters
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setResizable(false);

   }

  private void checkWin(int row, int col)
    {
      if(buttons[row][0].getText()==buttons[row][1].getText()&& buttons[row][1].getText()==buttons[row][2].getText())
        {
          gameWon = true;
          System.out.println(buttons[row][0].getText()+ " wins!!!");         
        }
    else  if(buttons[0][col].getText()==buttons[1][col].getText()&& buttons[1][col].getText()==buttons[2][col].getText())
       {
          gameWon = true;
          System.out.println(buttons[row][0].getText()+ " wins!!!");
       }
    }
  private void compTurn(int count)
   { 
    int randomMove=count;
    Random num = new Random();
    randomMove = num.nextInt(randomMove)+1;

     while(gameWon ==false)
      {
       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                      //Create grid of buttons for tic tac toe game
        {
         for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
          {                 
           if(buttons[i][j].isEnabled()==true)
            {
               randomMove--;

             if(randomMove==0 )
              {
                buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                moveCounter--;
                checkWin(i, j);
              }
             } 

            }
          }
        }
      }

private void initialize()             //Initialize tic tac toe game board
   {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());         //create main panel container to put layer others on top
      JPanel menu = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel game = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));                     //Create two more panels with layouts for buttons

      frame.add(mainPanel);                                         //add main container panel to frame

      mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,425));
      menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));                     //Setting dimensions of panels
      game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

      mainPanel.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);                   //Add two panels to the main container panel             
      mainPanel.add(game, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      menu.add(start, BorderLayout.WEST);                //Add both start/reset buttons to menu container panel
      menu.add(reset, BorderLayout.EAST);

      start.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
      reset.addActionListener(new myActionListener());

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                      //Create grid of buttons for tic tac toe game
     {
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {

         buttons[i][j] = new JButton();                //Instantiating buttons 
         buttons[i][j].setText("");
         buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);

         game.add(buttons[i][j]); 
         buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new myActionListener());        //Adding response event to buttons
        }
     }

  }

 private class myActionListener implements ActionListener
   {      //Implementing action listener for buttons
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
      {
       //Display X's or O's on the buttons  
       if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][0])                  //Checking which button is pressed
         {
           buttons[0][0].setText("X");
           buttons[0][0].setEnabled(false);
           moveCounter--;
           compTurn(moveCounter);
           checkWin(0,0);
         } 
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][1])
         {
           buttons[0][1].setText("X");
           buttons[0][1].setEnabled(false);
           moveCounter--;
           compTurn(moveCounter);
           checkWin(0,1);
         } 
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][0])
        {
          buttons[1][0].setText("X");  
          buttons[1][0].setEnabled(false);
          moveCounter--;
          compTurn(moveCounter);
          checkWin(1,0);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][1])
        {
          buttons[1][1].setText("X");
          buttons[1][1].setEnabled(false);
          moveCounter--;
          compTurn(moveCounter);
          checkWin(1,1);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][2])
        {
          buttons[1][2].setText("X");
          buttons[1][2].setEnabled(false);
          moveCounter--;
          compTurn(moveCounter); 
          checkWin(1,2);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][2])
        {
         buttons[2][2].setText("X");
         buttons[2][2].setEnabled(false);
         moveCounter--;
         compTurn(moveCounter);
         checkWin(2,2);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][2])
        {
         buttons[0][2].setText("X");
         buttons[0][2].setEnabled(false);
         moveCounter--;
         compTurn(moveCounter);
         checkWin(0,2);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][1])
        {
         buttons[2][1].setText("X");
         buttons[2][1].setEnabled(false);
         moveCounter--;
         compTurn(moveCounter);
         checkWin(2,1);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][0])
        {
         buttons[2][0].setText("X");
         buttons[2][0].setEnabled(false);
         moveCounter--;
         compTurn(moveCounter);
         checkWin(2,0);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == start)
         {
           turn = new JOptionPane("Do you want to go first?\n",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
           start.setEnabled(false);
         }
       else if(a.getSource() == reset)
         {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             { 
               for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                   buttons[i][j].setText(""); 
                   buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                   gameWon = false;
                }
             }
           }
       }
     }

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      TicGUI game = new TicGUI();         //main method and instantiating tic tac object and calling initialize function
      game.initialize();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following:

```
buttons[row][0].getText().equals(buttons[row][1].getText())
```

instead of:

```
buttons[row][0].getText()==buttons[row][1].getText()
```

**That also applies to all the other string comparisons in your checkWin method.**

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that, but am still getting frozen applet when running T_T

Comment: Actually, your answer is incorrect. `==` will work just fine for comparing Strings here, because the Strings bring compared are String literals, and thus are interned so the same String object will be used everywhere the same literal us coded.

Comment: It will work but it is, in general, preferable to use .equals() when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in you checkWon can't end while the game is I complete, but you can complete the game because the while loop is blocking it

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the AI ("compTurn()") Is running an indefinite loop, and never gives the player an actual turn. It instead constantly tries to do its turn. To combat this, add a regulating variable (I added "int whoseTurn" in the example fix below).

That only combats the runtime error, though. Another issue is that on MacOS devices (I tested it on MacOS X) the buttons are drawn before the backbuffer, and so the result is a blank backbuffer and a unplayable game. The solution to this is to draw the buttons after drawing the backbuffer, or just copy + paste the code of the buttons after the drawing backbuffer code.

There is yet another issue, whereas the "Start button is completely useless, and does not affect the game in any way. I removed that in the example code below.

The final issue is that your "checkWin" mehtod is simple, but oftentimes wrong. I have replaced it with a longer, more accurate win checking system.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class TicGUI extends JFrame 
{

JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");                    //Global frame and grid button variables
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");             //Create reset button for game
JOptionPane turn;
int moveCounter = 9;
boolean gameWon = false;
int WhoseTurn = 1;

public TicGUI()                                        //Tic tac default constructor which adds and dimensions Jframe
{
 super();
 frame.setSize(350, 355);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        //Setting dimension of Jframe and setting parameters
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setResizable(false);
 JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");                    //Global frame and grid button variables 
 JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");             //Create reset button for game
 JOptionPane turn;

}

private void checkWin(int row, int col)
{
    try {
    if (buttons[0][2].getText()==buttons[1][2].getText()&& buttons[1][2].getText()==buttons[2][2].getText()&& buttons[2][2].getText()==buttons[0][2].getText()&& buttons[1][2].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][2].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][2].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    if (buttons[0][1].getText()==buttons[1][1].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()==buttons[2][1].getText()&& buttons[2][1].getText()==buttons[0][1].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    if (buttons[0][0].getText()==buttons[1][0].getText()&& buttons[1][0].getText()==buttons[2][0].getText()&& buttons[2][0].getText()==buttons[0][0].getText()&& buttons[1][0].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][0].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][0].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    if (buttons[2][0].getText()==buttons[2][1].getText()&& buttons[2][1].getText()==buttons[2][2].getText()&& buttons[2][2].getText()==buttons[2][0].getText()&& buttons[2][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[2][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[2][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    if (buttons[1][0].getText()==buttons[1][1].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()==buttons[1][2].getText()&& buttons[1][2].getText()==buttons[1][0].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    if (buttons[0][0].getText()==buttons[0][1].getText()&& buttons[0][1].getText()==buttons[0][2].getText()&& buttons[0][2].getText()==buttons[0][0].getText()&& buttons[0][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[0][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[0][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
   if (buttons[0][0].getText()==buttons[1][1].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()==buttons[2][2].getText()&& buttons[2][2].getText()==buttons[0][0].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
   if (buttons[0][2].getText()==buttons[1][1].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()==buttons[2][0].getText()&& buttons[2][0].getText()==buttons[0][2].getText()&& buttons[1][1].getText()!="")
   {
      gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println(buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, buttons[1][1].getText()+ " wins!!!");
   }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        gameWon = true;
      WhoseTurn = 0;
      System.out.println("Stalemate");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Stalemate");
    }
}

private void compTurn(int count)
{ 
int randomMove=count;
Random num = new Random();
randomMove = num.nextInt(randomMove)+1;

 while(gameWon ==false & WhoseTurn ==2)
  {
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                      //Create grid of buttons for tic tac toe game
    {
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
      {                 
       if(buttons[i][j].isEnabled()==true)
        {
           randomMove--;

         if(randomMove==0 )
          {
            buttons[i][j].setText("O");
            buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            moveCounter--;
            checkWin(i, j);
            WhoseTurn = 1;
          }
         } 

        }
      }
    }
  }

private void initialize()             //Initialize tic tac toe game board
{
  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());         //create main panel container to put layer others on top
  JPanel menu = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel game = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));                     //Create two more panels with layouts for buttons

  frame.add(mainPanel);                                         //add main container panel to frame

  mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,425));
  menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));                     //Setting dimensions of panels
  game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

  mainPanel.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);                   //Add two panels to the main container panel             
  mainPanel.add(game, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  //Add both start/reset buttons to menu container panel
  menu.add(reset, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  reset.addActionListener(new myActionListener());

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                      //Create grid of buttons for tic tac toe game
 {
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
    {

     buttons[i][j] = new JButton();                //Instantiating buttons 
     buttons[i][j].setText("");
     buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);

     game.add(buttons[i][j]); 
     buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new myActionListener());        //Adding response event to buttons
    }
 }

}

private class myActionListener implements ActionListener
{      //Implementing action listener for buttons
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
  {
   //Display X's or O's on the buttons
   if(gameWon == false)
   {
   if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][0])                  //Checking which button is pressed
     {
       buttons[0][0].setText("X");
       buttons[0][0].setEnabled(false);
       WhoseTurn = 2;
       moveCounter--;
       compTurn(moveCounter);
       checkWin(0,0);
     } 
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][1])
     {
       buttons[0][1].setText("X");
       buttons[0][1].setEnabled(false);
       WhoseTurn = 2;
       moveCounter--;
       compTurn(moveCounter);
       checkWin(0,1);
     } 
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][0])
    {
      buttons[1][0].setText("X");  
      buttons[1][0].setEnabled(false);
      WhoseTurn = 2;
      moveCounter--;
      compTurn(moveCounter);
      checkWin(1,0);
    } 
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][1])
    {
      buttons[1][1].setText("X");
      buttons[1][1].setEnabled(false);
      WhoseTurn = 2;
      moveCounter--;
      compTurn(moveCounter);
      checkWin(1,1);
    }
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[1][2])
    {
      buttons[1][2].setText("X");
      buttons[1][2].setEnabled(false);
      WhoseTurn = 2;
      moveCounter--;
      compTurn(moveCounter); 
      checkWin(1,2);
    } 
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][2])
    {
     buttons[2][2].setText("X");
     buttons[2][2].setEnabled(false);
     WhoseTurn = 2;
     moveCounter--;
     compTurn(moveCounter);
     checkWin(2,2);
    } 
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[0][2])
    {
     buttons[0][2].setText("X");
     buttons[0][2].setEnabled(false);
     WhoseTurn = 2;
     moveCounter--;
     compTurn(moveCounter);
     checkWin(0,2);
    }
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][1])
    {
     buttons[2][1].setText("X");
     buttons[2][1].setEnabled(false);
     WhoseTurn = 2;
     moveCounter--;
     compTurn(moveCounter);
     checkWin(2,1);
    }
   else if(a.getSource() == buttons[2][0])
    {
     buttons[2][0].setText("X");
     buttons[2][0].setEnabled(false);
     WhoseTurn = 2;
     moveCounter--;
     compTurn(moveCounter);
     checkWin(2,0);
    }
   }
   if(a.getSource() == reset)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         { 
           for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                gameWon = false;
               buttons[i][j].setText(""); 
               buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
               moveCounter = 9;
               WhoseTurn = 1;

            }
         }
       }
  }
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  TicGUI game = new TicGUI();         //main method and instantiating tic tac object and calling initialize function
  game.initialize();
 }
}
```

If you continue to have problems, just ask!

- Jess Fan

JEF1056
[Musical artist, .Net programmer, Student]

https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/jef1056/id1139804160
https://play.google.com/store/music/artist/JEF1056?id=Aovo6cz54vkx2ekexyl7eom6nwy